# Restrict upload limit of a particular file type when uploading multiple files with fine uploader

Tags: php, jquery, fine-uploader

I'm relatively new to fine uploader plugin. So far i have been able to make uploads to my server. My application requirement permits both video files and image files.

Numerous number of image files are permitted but only one video file is allowed.

1) So is it possible to upload videos and images at the same time with fine uploader?

2) Is it possible also to restrict the number of video files that can be uploaded to just one when uploading, but image files would have no restriction?

```
var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
    request: {
        endpoint: '<?php echo _APIURL; ?>/catch_media/',
        inputName: 'file',
        params: {

        }
    },
    thumbnails: {
        placeholders: {
            waitingPath: 'assets/nexchange/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
            notAvailablePath: 'assets/nexchange/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
        }
    },
    validation: {
         itemLimit: 5,
         acceptFiles: ['image/*', 'video/mp4'],
         allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'mp4']
    },
    callbacks: {
        onAllComplete: function() {
            location.reload();
        }
    },
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true
});

qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload")).attach("click", function() {
     manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
});
```